# How to execute sbt all tests without truncating error logs

Tags: sbt

I have a project with multiple tests and I use 'sbt test' to execute all tests but when a test fails it is not all error description, only a few lines because the error is truncated, it forces me to execute once again that test individually to read the complete error log.

Is there a way to execute all tests with the extended error?